# ImportError: cannot import name 'GceClusterResolver'

Tags: python, tensorflow, importerror, tensorflow-slim

I am following the guide for installing TensorFlow Slim, and I faced this error.

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'GceClusterResolver'
```

I searched online and found some questions on Stack Overflow regarding "*import error cannot import name xxx*", but none of them is the same as mine. I've tried their solutions too but they didn't work.

This is the complete error message. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
python -c "import tensorflow.contrib.slim as slim; eval = slim.evaluation.evaluate_once"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/__init__.py", line 31, in <module>
    from tensorflow.contrib import cluster_resolver
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/cluster_resolver/__init__.py", line 26, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.distribute.cluster_resolver.gce_cluster_resolver import GceClusterResolver
ImportError: cannot import name 'GceClusterResolver'
```

Answer (score 0):

I found out that i was using `tflearn` with `tensorflow 2` but tflearn is not compatible with tensorflow 2. I just falled back to a tensorflow 1 version.

```
# uninstall both libs
pip uninstall tensorflow
pip uninstall tflearn

# install the compatible version
pip install tflearn
pip install tensorflow==1.15
```